# Print PDF from IOS using JS

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf

As of some time now Apple has provided a way to « print a page as a PDF file »

Using the share button on an iphone or Ipad and going to « Create PDF » the device creates a pdf which can be saved.

Now this is only available on Safari.

I built a PWA where the Safari controls are not visible. Is there a way to create a link inside the page to trigger the Create PDF option ?

If you go to this page:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_print

There is a way, with a button to trigger the Print option on the device... now that shows that communication between a JS / HTML tag can trigger a Device option as AirPrint... Is there a similar way to trigger the Create PDF ?

I know that the print() option is standard to the web and that ios’s Create PDF is « proprietary » to apple...

I have been searching around on the web for a solution but the keywords of my search only provide tutorials on how to Print PDF on Safari dated at the time where this option was introduced...

If anyone has a solutions ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Sorry no answers.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called jsPDF which generates PDFs using Javascript alone

- Example create a "Hello World" PDF file.

> Default export is a4 paper, portrait, using milimeters for units

```
var doc = new jsPDF()

doc.text('Hello world!', 10, 10)
doc.save('a4.pdf')
```

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.5/jspdf.debug.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks i should have talked about jsPDF. I am not looking for an actual library.

I have used jsPDF in the past and works not always as expected and is way more complicated that it needs to be.

The PWA i created is a simple project management i use for my company (locksmith) something i share reports with subcontractors i hire about some projects and clients and i am searching for a way to print a PDF (as i already have generated the report in PHP)

While on my "app" inside Safari i can do it perfectly... but on the PWA there are no buttons to create the actual PDF.